# Querying in elasticsearch to get a json object as output

Tags: json, elasticsearch, search, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-dsl

```
{
    "key":
    [
        {
            "text": "I noticed when you came up he's even",
            "start": 0.0,
            "duration": 4.68
        },
        {
            "text": "playing with a little bit your your",
            "start": 3.3,
            "duration": 5.07
        }
    ]
}
```

I have huge amount of files in this format and i have to write a query for only getting the text
and its start.But,I'm getting the whole file in which the text is present as output.

if i write the query like this:

```
{
    "query":
    {
        "term":
        {
            "key.text": "came"
        }
    }
}
```

then i should get only

```
{
    "text": "I noticed when you came up he's even",
    "start": 0.0,
    "duration": 4.68
}
```

as output but Instead im getting the whole file as output.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html might be useful for you please try and let me know

Comment: The link says this:- If a nested query matches one or more nested objects in a document, it returns the document as a hit. This applies even if other nested objects in the document don’t match the query.

Comment: But I want only the object which matches the query but not the entire parent document.

Comment: You need to use https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/inner-hits.html, its clearly mention in the same document I pinged

Comment: Thank you Amit.finally found what I have been looking for.Have a great day.

Comment: I have edited your question to be more readable and summarize our discussion as an answer so that its more useful for community, please mark my answer by clicking the right arrow in front of answer, Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [inner hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/inner-hits.html) of [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) to fetch only the item in a array matches your search query.